# TypeError: expect(...).toBeA is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, node.js-connect

this is my message.test.js file.

```
  var expect = require('expect');

  var {generateMessage} = require('./message');

  describe('generateMessage', () => {
    it('should generate correct message object', () => {
      var from = 'Jen';
      var text = 'Some message';
      var message = generateMessage(from, text);

      expect(message.createdAt).toBeA('number');
      expect(message).toInclude({from, text});
  });
});
```

ERROR:
priya@priya-pro:~/node-chat-app$ npm test

> node-chat-app@1.0.0 test /home/priya/node-chat-app
>   mocha server/**/*.test.js
>   generateMessage
>    1) should generate correct message object

0 passing (12ms)
  1 failing

1) generateMessage
       should generate correct message object:
     TypeError: expect(...).toBeA is not a function
      at Context.it (server/utils/message.test.js:12:31)

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Help me...

Comment: It should be `.toBe` instead of  `.toBeA`?

Comment: Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected value to be:
  "number"
Received:
  1522837788748

Difference:

  Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received number.
      at Context.it (server/utils/message.test.js:12:31)

Comment: Follow your error message. I think `message.createdAt` return number instead of string.

Comment: Yes bcoz of the use of .toBe instead of .toBeA

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ownership of the [expect library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect-legacy) has been donated to [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html) from v21+. Since then some of the method names and their functionality has been changed. The following modification to code will help to overcome issue.

```
var expect = require('expect');
var {generateMessage}  = require('./message');

describe('generateMessage', () => {
   it('should generate correct message object', () => {

       var from = 'Jen';
       var text = 'Some message';
       var message = generateMessage(from, text);

       expect(typeof message.createdAt).toBe('number');
       expect(message).toMatchObject({from, text});
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar way, I made a basic syntax error, my terminal was saying:

**TypeError: sum(...).toBe is not a function.**

Here's the code I was using in both my **main.js** file and my **main.test.js** file:

↓ **main.js** ↓

```
function sum(a, b){

return a + b

}


module.exports =  sum;
```

↓ **main.test.js** ↓

```
const sum = require('./main')
   


test('adds two numbers together', ()=>{

    expect(sum(2,2).toBe(4))
    
    
    })
```

I kept thinking that my **module.exports/require** syntax was somehow wrong. After many attempts, I meticulously followed a Jest.js tutorial - and the unit test passed! I then compared it with my nonfunctional copy - and I spotted the error in my **main.test.js** file :

**main.test.js**

```
    expect(sum(2,2).toBe(4))
```

what it needs to be is:

```
    expect(sum(2,2)).toBe(4)
```

Notice the position of the parentheses - rather than chaining the .toBe() matcher to the expect() function, I was unwittingly passing .toBe() into the expect() function with my sum(2,2) value, resulting in : **TypeError: sum(...).toBe is not a function** !

A super obvious mistake in hindsight, but hopefully this helps someone in the future! :-)